# mocking in jest not returning multiple values

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to mock a private variable in typescript using jest, below is my mocking code

```
import { ClassToMock } from "../../../commons/abc/ClassToMock";



jest.mock("../../../commons/abc/ClassToMock", () => {
    return {
      ClassToMock: function () {
        return ({
          funToMock: mockFunToMock
        });
      }
    };
});

test("", async () => {
funToMock.mockResolvedValueOnce([objA,objB]).mockResolvedValueOnce([objC]);
serviceToTest.fun() // fun internally uses classToMock
});
```

Now the problem is `[objA,objB]` are returned correctly but when second time I do the function call `objC` is never returned.
Not sure whats going wrong

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete, reproducible code and the debug details

Comment: How to recognize that it is never returned?